# How does WooCommerce internally relate products-orders-coupons-members?

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, migration

I am fairly new to WooCommerce and want to know how it internally relates products to orders to coupons to members.

The reason is I have a large store on live. I also have a staging website that has had the new products built to match the old products but were not actually moved/migrated. (Different ids)

I'm trying to use WP All Export/Import to now bring in the information from the LIVE store to the staging one. However, I have real concerns I will not be able to relate/match the live products to the staging products.

Can this be accomplished by using SKU instead? If so, do those changes modify the orders or will there be mismatches of ids?

Any advice or links you can share to details about how to accomplish this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: All importing and exporting of any type of content via wordpress uses IDs to match, overwrite and delete. They would need the same IDs or else they will create new products on the staging server for the products that dont have a matching ID.

Comment: This webtoffee [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) will handle product import export using SKU

Answer (score 0):

Using WP All Import it is possible to select SKU instead of id as a unique identifier when importing and updating products.